# gulp minify-css strips out comments in scss files

Tags: sass, minify, gulp

I am trying to be a good boy and minify my css with gulp. I am currently using gulp-sass (not gulp-ruby-sass) and it does not seem to have inbuilt minifying. So now I am using gulp-minify-css to pipe some minifying into my compiling. The problem is that it now strips out all of my comments. both `/*comment*/` and `//comment`. This is not ideal, as i need the initial comment to setup my wordpress theme.

So I looked in the documentation (https://github.com/jonathanepollack/gulp-minify-css/wiki), and it looks like there is an option for this called keepSpecialComments.

So I have tried the following in my gulpfile:

```
.pipe(minifycss({keepSpecialComments: '*'}))
```

and

```
.pipe(minifycss({keepSpecialComments: *}))
```

The first one still strips out the comments. the second one reports an error. So I think i might get the formatting wrong?

can anyone help me here?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The second example you have there has the asterisk `*` sitting out in the open — it's not a string.  That's why it reports an error.

The docs state that the default setting to to save all *special* comments.  If you click through to `clean-css`, you will see that *special comments* refers to [comments that have an exclamation mark (`!`) to note that they are important](https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css#how-to-preserve-a-comment-block).  Try changing your comment to look like this, and I bet it will retain it without any configuration at all.

```
/*!
put your settings here
*/
```

If Wordpress is incapable of working with the special comment, for some reason, then you can use [`gulp-replace`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-replace) to correct the comment before saving it, like this:

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

// ... sass, compress-css, etc ...
.pipe(replace('/*!', '/*'))
// ... gulp.dest, etc ...
```

This will remove the exclamation mark from the comment.  I wouldn't bother doing this unless Wordpress fails.

Comment: Missed the bit with the special comment. Wordpress is fine with it, so it sorted everything. Thanks!

Comment: I guess it pays to read the docs. Thanks for clearing this up!